# Segmentation fault in a C program that create a matrix NxN of 1 and 0 from a file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix, segmentation-fault

I have the following problem:
I have a file, let's says **file1.dat** that contains the following data:

```
1 2
3 1
2 1
1 3
3 2
```

I would like to write a program in C that reads from this file and create an NxN matrix in a new file, with 1 if the i-th and j-th elements of the matrix are both contained in the **file1.dat**, 0 otherwise. In this case I would have a 3x3 matrix like

```
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 0
```

The difficulty for me is to make it clear to the computer that the numbers in the **file1.dat** are the coordinates of the matrix elements where it should put a 1 and in the other sites to put a 0.

As suggest from one of the users I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 131827

int main(void){
int x,y;
int matrix[N][N];
FILE *ifp = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
FILE *ofp = fopen("matrice_A_1.dat", "w");
while(fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &x, &y) != EOF){
x--;
y--;
matrix[x][y] = 1;
}
fclose(ifp);
for(x=0; x<N; x++){
  for(y=0; y<N; y++){
fprintf(ofp, "%d ", matrix[x][y]);
  }
  fprintf(ofp, "\n");
}
fclose(ofp);
return(0);
}
```

but I've used another **file1.dat** of 131827 rows (and 2 colums), but it gives me a segmentation fault error. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean if the ith and jth elements of the matrix are both contained in file1.dat?

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as this:

```
// Define static matrix containing all zeroes.
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 3;
int m[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
```

Then to read...

```
int i, j;
FILE * fp = fopen( "file1.dat", "rt" );
if( fp != NULL ) {
    while( 2 == fscanf( fp, "%d%d", &i, &j ) {
        if( i < 1 || i > ROWS || j < 1 || j > COLS ) {
             printf( "Bad address: %d, %d\n", i, j );
             continue;
        }
        m[i-1][j-1] = 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Create NxN matrix with input coordinates used to set element val=1; rest 0
void doStuff(int N){
    int x,y;
    int matrix[N][N] = {{0}};
    FILE *ifp = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
    FILE *ofp = fopen("out.dat", "w");
    while(fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &x, &y) != EOF){
        x--;
        y--;
        matrix[x][y] = 1;
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    for(x=0; x<N; x++){
        for(y=0; y<N; y++){
            fprintf(ofp, "%d ", matrix[x][y]);
        }
        fprintf(ofp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(ofp);
}
```

Comment: kchoi your program give me lots of errors and warning: I tried to copy it and the results are the following:matrice.c: In function ‘doStuff’:
file.c:5:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
file.c:5:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
filee.c:5:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘matrix[0]’) [enabled by default]
file.c:5:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
file.c:5:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘matrix’) [enabled by default]

Comment: I would replace N in int matrix[N][N] with numbers in that case... C doesn't allow variable size array.